# Hamming distance triangle inequality

Tags: metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

How to prove triangle inequality of metric space for Hamming distance between the bit strings of length n?
$$d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$$

Comment: Hint: For every $j$ such that $x_j\neq y_j$, either $z_j\neq x_j$ or $z_j\neq y_j$.

Comment: I've already tried using this hint

Comment: Well, I mean... it should solve the exercise pretty much by itself.

Comment: What is the equality CONDITION ??

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side contribution occurs for all those coordinates $i$ such that $x_i\neq y_i$. Now, fixing a coordinate $i$, if $x_i\neq y_i$ then it is clear that $x_i\neq z_i$ or $y_i\neq z_i$. Thus, for all those coordinate $i$ contributing in $d(x, y)$ will contribute in $d(x, z)$ or $d(y, z)$. This gives us the desired inequality.